# What do I have to insert in sql foreign key column between two tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have made two tables, `whole_data` and `room_table`. I took the id of `whole_data` as a foreign key in `room_table` and I am inserting data through the HTML form, not manually. So now I am confused, what do I have to insert in the field of foreign key in `room table`. Look at the code and queries made. If you look at the insertion in `room_table`, then the fourth column value I left it blank, because I don't know what I have to insert, all I need is the primary id of the `whole_data` table.

```
$whole_tab = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS whole_tab (
    p_id int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    agentName varchar(400),
    price int(100),
    grossArea varchar(100),
    postCode varchar(50),
    pricePerSqFt varchar(100),
    prType varchar(100),
    contact varchar(200),
    prDesc varchar(5000),
    prImgs varchar(3000),
    prPdf varchar(1000),
    prAddress varchar(1000)
  )";
$con->query($whole_tab);//Connect to table
//Table one end

  $room_tab = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_tab (
    r_id int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    bedRooms int(100),
    bathRooms int(100),
    otherList varchar(3000),
    from_p_id int(100) REFERENCES whole_tab(p_id) 
   )";
  $con->query($room_tab);//Connect to table

//INSERTION

$ins_whole_tab = "INSERT INTO whole_tab VALUES(NULL,'$agName','$prPrice','$prGrossArea','$postCode','$prPerSqFt','$radioSel','$prContact','$prDesc','$imgPathsJson','$pdfPath','$prAddress')";
$con -> query($ins_whole_tab);


//Insert Data
$ins_room_tab = "INSERT INTO room_tab VALUES(NULL,'$bedRNum','$bathRNum','$otherRDet','')";
$con -> query($ins_room_tab);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`last_insert_id()` returns the value of the last auto increment id that was inserted. Use it in your query:

```
$ins_room_tab = "INSERT INTO room_tab VALUES(NULL,'$bedRNum','$bathRNum','$otherRDet',last_insert_id())";
```